# Why don't my questions appear in the Top Questions list?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that neither of my last two questions (possibly the ones before as well) appeared in the Top Questions list. Doesn't this list show the most recent questions/most recently answered questions? What determines if a question appears in the list?

*(no wonder my questions only get a handful of views, and no answers.)*

Comment: The list on the frontpage (if that's what you mean) is filtered differently for everyone. The algorithm is explained somewhere on meta.

Comment: for one of your questions the total number of followers in the tags used is just over 100. Don't expect the same view count as in let's say JavaScript or *cough* PHP