# When do modified questions appear on top again?

Tags: discussion, front-page

The last days I noticed that not every modified question appears again on top of the frontpage.

But some are.

[image]

Is there a special amount of modifications where the questions appears on top again to avoid just changing very small part to get more views?
Or do I have to change e.g. at least 50% of the question to make it appearing again?

It would be useful to know that if you still working at your question and update it regularly.

If the question appears e.g. just for the first modification again, it would be better to wait longer to have more information to update. Because if you make a bigger update and the question doesn't appear on top nearly no one will see it.
Than I think it's not worth to invest a bigger amount of work in rewrite the question if just one or two persons will see it.

In [THIS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312693/why-dont-my-questions-appear-in-the-top-questions-list) question CodeCaster wrote in the comments that the algorithm of the frontpage is explained somewhere on meta, but I was not able to find anything.

So how does that work, or is it a "secret"?

(Maybe I just didn't look carefully and overlooked the modified questions, but I don't think so.)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83078/do-frontpage-questions-learn-from-user-preferences, https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you! So the modification of the question has no influence on that? I don't understand the table at all... what are all the numbers in there.. 1500 questions?...which have one of my favourite tasks? 1000 tag score? Sorry =(

Comment: Every edit pushes a question to the frontpage, it's just not necessarily visible on _your_ frontpage.